# how to stretch the button to full fill the container

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when i use react native button i cannot strech it, the blow is the style that i used for the button

```
myButtonStyle: {
     flex: 1,
     borderRadius: 5,
     alignSelf: 'stretch',
     backgroundColor: 5,
     borderWidth: 1,
     borderColor: '#007aff',
     marginRight: 5,
     marginLeft: 5
   }
```

and the button itself:

```
<Button
          style={myButtonStyle}
            title="Learn More"
            color="#841584"
            accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
          />
```

and this is the style of the button wrapper

```
myCardSectioStyle: {
    borderBottomWidth: 4,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ffff00',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderColor: '#6600ff',
    position: 'relative'
  }
```

Comment: Can we see the styles of the parent container the button sits inside of?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i did

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to full fill a child view to it's parent.

1. Use `position: 'absolute'` and then set `top, right, bottom, right` all to zero.
2. The parent view sets `alignItems` and `justifyContent` both to `stretch` (This is the default value, so just don't set those styles), and the child sets `flex` style.

**If your container just has one child that positioning to `relative`, you can use both two ways.**

*BTW: Use `StyleSheet.absoluteFill`(see http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#absolutefill) you can get a StyleSheet object, and use `StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject`(see http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html#absolutefillobject) you can get an object that has those style properties*

**If you have one more child views, you can use the first way on that child view.**

Note: I created a demo on Expo Snack at https://snack.expo.io/HkIyVVDHW, you can preview it on Expo client.

Comment: why `  alignSelf: 'stretch',`  didn't work? it overrides the parent alighness, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I just test your code ant it works fine. See https://snack.expo.io/Sk4wcvdrZ. Are there other child views in the container?

Comment: One would think the world would move on, but no, we're back to being forced to hack such a simple thing as stretching proportions to parent dimensions. I just tested and `width` and `height` set to `"100%"` is still not working with `position: absolute`  However, at least this works :-)